# How do I format a one line JSON string

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm creating a GUI in Visual Studio which is going to fetch JSON data from an API to display in a text box, and I want it to be displayed formatted so it's readable.

I have tried to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` library to solve the problem, but it seems like it does not work on one liners of JSON and must take an object containing different types of JSON data.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string API_Key = "000000000000000000000"; // URL with API key containing the JSON data

    string JSON_Data_URL = $"https://www.nobil.no/api/server/datadump.php?apikey={API_Key}&countrycode=NOR&fromdate=2005-01-01&format=json";
    LoadJSON.Increment(-100); // Reset loadbar
    string JSON_Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wc.DownloadString(JSON_Data_URL), Formatting.Indented); // Format JSON data

    DataResults.Text = JSON_Data; // Add JSON data to textbox
    LoadJSON.Increment(100); // Display when the JSON data is fetched
}
```

I thought it would output an formatted JSON string, but seems like it instead is just adding backslashes to the JSON. I also tried to replace the backslashes with a new line and 4 spaces, but that didn't look right either.

**Edit**

This is not a duplicate as the problem seemed to be that I needed to convert the string to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you are serializing a string and not an object.

```
string JSON_Data = "..." // Get your json from your API
object JSON_Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON_Data);
string JSON_Data_Formatted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSON_Object, Formatting.Indented);
```